# How to stop a (malicious) endless loop

Tags: php, attack-prevention

Few days ago someone tried to crack my site using a Remote File Inclusion attack.
The attack was blocked by my Web Application Firewall, but I was curious about the file.
So I downloaded it started to examine it.

First of all, the file deletes itself:
`unlink($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])`

Then it starts and endless loop awaiting orders from an irc chat:

```
do{
   //awaiting orders and executing them
}while(1)
```

I was wondering: if I ever get infected by something like this:

1. How can I detect the infection? I have to rely on my hosting security system?
2. How can I stop that? It's an endless loop loaded in memory, should I ask my hosting to restart the service or kill my php process?

Comment: Ask the hosting service to stop network access, reinstall from backup, apply security patches, test your site, and cross your fingers that it doesn't get infected the 5 seconds after it goes on-line. "Every time somebody starts a site running PHP, a kitten is killed"...

Comment: @DeerHunter The last sentence is highly misleading. PHP is neither more nor less secure than any other server-side language. I have yet to hear any sound argument back the claim that PHP is _less_ secure than its friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting compromised is never a good feeling. That endless loop is a process. every process has an process id. If you don't have ssh access (and I assume you don't) try finding the process id by PHP script:

```
php system("ps aux");
```

Locate the name of the file for example `php endless_loop.php` which is located in the last column of the returned list. In the second column you find the process id. When you have the process id all you have to do is execute another script:

```
php system("kill proccess_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Since the trojans tries to connect to external IRC server, it would make connection to external server. [Netstat](http://www.computerweekly.com/tip/How-to-use-a-netstat-command-in-Windows-to-watch-open-ports) would help you to identify suspicious connections. Also, trojan tries to make itself look like system process, **chkrootkit** would be more helpful instead of using **ps**.
2. If you found the trojan, you may follow advise from HEX to kill a process. Be advise a full installation would be more appropriate to a compromised system.

Comment: Exactly! when you are compromised once you are never safe again unless you reinstall. But as far as I could understand tampe125 is a hosting user. and I doubt he has rights to use chrootkit or do fresh-install. Also another important issue is to check the code of his web app. Because the hacker may use the same bug times and times again.

Comment: thank you! however, I'm not hacked, since they tried to use an non-existant bug (Wordpress bug, and I'm using Joomla!)

Comment: BIOS may get infected as well. you are going too far Oleg. We are talking about php scripts your are talking about images.